# "Now playing hotkey" media player addon or software for *nix?

Tags: media-player

Looking for an addon/app or media player that provides a 'Now Playing' hotkey output to clipboard feature, similar to that of AMIP (advanced mIRC integration plugin) that runs natively in Linux - without wine.

AMIP is heavily tied to Windows API, which is a shame.

Does anyone know of anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a few hours with no luck, I took the plunge and threw this together.

Just a heads up to anyone planning on using this -- **I doubt this is very efficient**, and I'm sure there's a better way -- but this works great for me.

If *efficiency* is an issue, perhaps this is not the best way for you.

Personally I have this set up run on a hotkey in my window manager (CTRL + Shift + Z), and it works great! :)

***Note: xclip, lsof and ffmpeg are required.***

Output: 
`np: A Perfect Circle - The Noose.flac [801 kb/s] in vlc`

```
#!/bin/sh

mediaplayers="vlc totem rhythmbox banshee mplayer gnome-mplayer"

# path to ffmpeg
ffmpeg=$(which ffmpeg)
[ -z "$ffmpeg" ] && echo "ffmpeg not installed" && exit 1


for mediaplayer in $mediaplayers
do
  pat="([^\w-]$mediaplayer)"
  if ps ux | grep -P $pat | grep -vq grep; then
    #mediaplayer detected
    file=`lsof -F n -c "$mediaplayer" | egrep -i "^.*\.(mp3|flac|m4a)$" | sed 's/^n//g'`

    if [ ! -z "$file" ]; then
          if echo $file | grep -q m4a; then
          bitrate=`ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep -v Estimating | grep bitrate | sed 's/^.*[*:].//g'`
          # crazy bash string manipulation (my m4a's have no metadata -- unsure if yours do)
          echo -n "np: ${file##*/} [$bitrate] in $mediaplayer"  | xclip -selection clipboard
          exit 1
        fi

        if echo $file | grep -q mp3; then
          # mp3 metadata
          perf=`ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep -v album_artist | grep artist | sed 's/^.*[*:].//g'`
          title=`ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep -v Image | grep -v cover | grep title | sed 's/^.*[*:].//g'`
          bitrate=`ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep -v Estimating | grep bitrate | sed 's/^.*[*:].//g'`
          if [ ! -z "$title" ] && [ ! -z "$perf" ]; then
            echo -n "np: $perf - $title.mp3 [$bitrate] in $mediaplayer"  | xclip -selection clipboard
            exit 1
          fi
        fi

        if echo $file | grep -q flac; then
          # flac metadata
          perf=`ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep ARTIST | sed 's/^.*[*:].//g'`
          title=`ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep -v Image | grep TITLE | sed 's/^.*[*:].//g'`
          bitrate=`ffmpeg -i "$file" 2>&1 | grep bitrate | sed 's/^.*[*:].//g'`
          echo File: "$file"
          if [ ! -z "$title" ] && [ ! -z "$perf" ]; then
            echo -n "np: $perf - $title.flac [$bitrate] in $mediaplayer"  | xclip -selection clipboard
            exit 1
          fi
        fi

      fi
    else
      echo -n "No music playing or no player detected..." | xclip -selection clipboard
  fi
done
```

**FYI, I am 'archenemy'. I could not remember my account details when I made the question.**